# Submitting individual entries from the same page -> with multiple forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following form:

```
@foreach($pleyers as $player)

    <form action="/saveplayer" method="POST">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6">
                <p>{{$player['name']}}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label>Score</label>
                <input type="number" name="{{$player['id']}}"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

MY FUNCTION

```
function savePlayer(Request $request){
    
   

}
```

How do I save the player scores individually, if the foreach generates 3 forms

Comment: add submit button into each form?

Comment: I am guessing your question now is, how to know what the name of your request parameter would be? Don't use `name="{{$player['id']}}"`. Put the player id into a hidden field with a static name, and use a static name for the number input field as well.

Comment: modify this line after adding submit button

                <input type="number" name="score" value="{{$player['id']}}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$player['id']}}"/>
so in controller u can access values as score,id